# Comment Form Text Area Breaks in IE7 and IE 8

Tags: html, css

On Single page the comment form of Text area is moves Forwarded with threaded comment. Please click on reply to have a look.
 A wordpress site.
demo sites example :
http://dikkers.rtcamp.info/?p=205

Comment: My Question is, when i am clicking on reply button the text area moves toward left in IE...

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the indentation of the reply comments?  There is a style that is applied to each child comment such as depth-3, depth-4 ect.  There is probably a way to turn this off within your admin - however, you can always just adjust these classes within your stylesheet to remove their left margins.

Comment: OK, I guess I didn't follow.  The reply form, if that is what you are talking about, is nested within the div that determines the level of indentation.... depth-3, depth-4 etc.  If you want the reply form to appear like it does on the bottom, you could ad some style to override the indentation.  Something like:

.depth-4 .reply {margin-left: -20px}

You'd have to customize that per depth level, and test it out.